# Are there good free MKV writer libraries for commercial usage?

Tags: c++, video, mkv

I need to write a C++ code that writes files in MKV format (or in any other format supporting VP8/9 and Opus codecs with embedded metadata). Is there a good portable library with a license which allows static linkage (probably a BSD-like)?

Thanks.